# How can I get the android kernel version via adb (or via Python command)?

Tags: android, python, kernel, adb

I need the kernel version from a device with Android OS to use in a Python script. How can I get this value?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the following command:

```
adb shell cat /proc/version
```

For my phone I received the following output:

```
Linux version 2.6.35.7-g3cc95e3 (peter@boris) (gcc version 4.4.3 (GCC) ) #3 PREEMPT Thu Aug 18 14:34:17 EDT 2011
```